# How can I add reminders table to my database?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send reset password email and I need to use `reminders` table in `laravel`. I migrated tables from `laravel` but there isn't any `reminders` table.

```
public function password(Request $request){
    $user = User::where("email_addr",$request->email)->first();
    if($user == null){
        return "NOTFOUND"; 
    }

    else{
        $sentinelUser = Sentinel::findById($user->id);
        $reminder = Reminder::exists($sentinelUser) ? : Reminder::create($sentinelUser);
        $this->sendEmail($user, $reminder->code);

        return "RESET";
   }

public function sendEmail($user, $code){

    Mail::send(
        'email.forgot',
        ['user' => $user, 'code' => $code],
        function($message) use ($user){
            $message->to($user->email);
            $message->subject("Hello $user->name" , "Reset password.");
        }
    );

}
```

When I tried to send email, I got an error like this:

> "Class 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Reminder' not found".

How can I add reminders table?

Comment: Have added it to your composer file and installed it?

Answer (score 0):

open your Laravel config file located at config/app.php and add the following lines.

In the `$providers` array add the following

```
Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class,
```

In the `$aliases` array add the following:

```
'Activation' => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation::class,
'Reminder'   => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Reminder::class,
'Sentinel'   => Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel::class,
```

In Controller file add `use Reminder` after `namespace`.

Comment: I did. But I got an error like this:  Base table or view not found: db_name.reminders' doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. You need to update composer. When I updated the composer, reminders table appears in my database.

```
composer update
```